# Difference between authenticated and unauthenticated access in cognito identity pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0

Whats the difference between authenticated and unauthenticated access in Cognito identity pool. When we specify an on-premise identity provider in cognito identity pool, will user records be created again in cognito identity pool.? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticated access is where a user has successfully logged in using the credentials from the Cognito User Pool.

An [unauthentcated access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) user is basically an anonymous user. This means temporary credentials can be used to retrieve access to AWS services that would be serving public content that should not be behind any security wall.